# Won't group by?

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a really wierd issue, that i cannot GROUP by. If i do, it won't show the "best time". It's kinda wierd.

Here is the SQL String which works (But it shows the same quiz 4 times, which it shouldn't!)

```
SELECT distinct a.quiz_id, a.time, b.end, b.images, b.prize_title 
FROM entries a, quiz b 
WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND a.member = '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
ORDER BY a.time ASC
```

Screen of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3b4s.jpg

This show NOT the best time (Fastest time => ASC)

```
SELECT distinct a.quiz_id, a.time, b.end, b.images, b.prize_title 
FROM entries a, quiz b 
WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND a.member = '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
GROUP BY a.quiz_id 
ORDER BY a.time ASC
```

Screen of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdR2Y.jpg

The column "a.time" is miliseconds and the column is DOUBLE.

Comment: Show your table structure, it doesn't sound correct, avoid using `time` it might collide, change it to some other name..

Comment: I do'nt see an ORDER BY in your example query.  Can you show sample table data, sample query, and sample query results that you are getting when you think ORDER BY is not working properly.

Comment: It would be better to have a column of "time" and another column for "micro/mill" seconds and order first by time then by the micro

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-float.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT MIN(a.time), a.quiz_id, a.time, b.end, b.images, 
b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND 
a.member = '".$_SESSION['id']."' GROUP BY a.quiz_id
```

Comment: Doesn't get the best score in that example. SELECT MIN(a.time), a.quiz_id, a.time, b.end, b.images, 
b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND 
a.member = '".$_SESSION['id']."' GROUP BY a.quiz_id ORDER BY a.time ASC

Comment: If by `best score` you mean `lowest time` - it should - you should not have the `order by` clause anymore though.

Comment: It did the work, thanks so much man.  Please confirm this SELECT MIN(a.time) as correctTime, a.quiz_id, a.time, b.end, b.images, 
b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND 
a.member = 1 GROUP BY a.quiz_id

Comment: You're welcome...Happy Coding. What do you want me to confirm about it?

Comment: Also, it's a very good idea to avoid using field names like `class`, `time`, `date`, `start`, `end`, or anything else that could be seen as a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Avoid `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same query (you only need one or the other).

Comment: I am not familiar with HAVING. Can you help me though? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't work as expected because `GROUP BY` is applied *before* `ORDER BY`. It would just sort the results after the grouping -- and there's only one result left.

Try the following:

```
SELECT a.quiz_id, a.time, b.end, b.images, b.prize_title
FROM entries a
JOIN quiz b ON a.quiz_id = b.id
ORDER BY a.time ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, but your description doesn't tell the whole story.  The JOIN produces an intersection set, which probably eliminates the duplication that the GROUP BY or DISTINCT would eliminate.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Not working. Showing them all, and not only the best score. Did try  SELECT a.quiz_id, a.time, b.end, b.images, b.prize_title
FROM entries a
JOIN quiz b ON a.quiz_id = b.id and a.member = 1
ORDER BY a.time ASC

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that condition. Just add `LIMIT 1` to the query. (Edited my answer accordingly)